# Website not loading. No access logs created

Tags: apache2, virtualmin

I have a server running apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04 and Virtualmin software. For one of these domains, the site just stops loading and timeout occurs in the browser. When this happens there are no access logs created so I think the request never even reaches apache? Other domains on the same server continues working just fine.

When I restart apache, the site starts working again. It happened a few weeks back but I ignored it as a one off situation but it happened again. I'm not sure how to diagnose the issue without any logs.

Comment: Add monitoring and start collecting system logs, rather than  just looking for Apache logs and waiting to see symptoms in your web browser.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what to do? Monitoring what? Which log file exactly?

Comment: System logs is stuff in /var/log: messages, auth, daemon and so on.